# Can I use a command module code and make it python

Tags: python, command-line

Is there a way to access a library that I can access on command line on python that is connected that library

One example would be

```
cd Desktop/GoPiGo/Software/Python/Examples/GPS_Bot/
sudo python gps.py
```

Because I know that that works on the command line I don't know how to adapt it to python

Any websites or tutorials you link would be welcome as I am a fledgling programmer and have just started learning about the command line.

Comment: Sort of unclear on what you want, are you trying to execute shell commands through python?

Comment: yes the sudo python.GPS command in the library Desktop/GoPiGo/Software/Python/Examples/GPS_Bot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run commands to the console, you have to use `subprocess`.

You must first import the modules, then run the command. 
You are using the system's commands, so you must import `sys` as well.

Let me know if this works.

```
import subprocess
    import sys
    process = subprocess.Popen(['cd', 'Desktop/GoPiGo/Software/Python/Examples/GPS_Bot/', 'sudo', 'python', 'gps.py"'])
```

Answer (score -1):

Look into https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

For example, you can run the command (I have not tested this particular usage):

```
subprocess.check_call(['cd', 'Desktop/GoPiGo/Software/Python/Examples/GPS_Bot/', 'sudo', 'python', 'gps.py'], shell=True)
```